# Using spirals to draw log scale?

Tags: logarithms, polar-coordinates

Taking inspiration from the fact every math textbook in existence puts a picture of a nautilus shell on its logarithms chapter, I did some research, and found that many different spirals (most easily defined in polar coordinates) had a $\ln()$ term in their arc length (that is, once the integral was evaluated).

I kept trying to play with some functions to see if their arc length was just $\ln(\theta)$ or $\ln(\theta)+\text{some constant}$ or something. This is because for an unrelated project, I will need to draw a logarithmic scale (of any base) and it would be cool to spiral up a piece of paper and draw lines along certain angles and unrolling a precise log scale. (If you're wondering why I'm not printing it, it's because I may not be using paper that my printer can handle, such as cardboard)

So, I'm hoping somebody has already stumbled onto such a result and could maybe lead me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're asking for - but have you heard of the Riemann surface of $\log(z),z\in\mathbb C$?

Comment: No I haven't, I will check it out. Although at first glance I don't see how it would help me accomplish what I'm set out to do. Interesting, nonetheless. Thanks